# in node js simple condition don't match?

Tags: node.js

i'want to test a password before to offer access but don't working

in my app :

```
    function isAuthentificated(req, res, next){
 fs.readFile('bin/config', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log(typeof req.session.pwd)
    console.log(typeof data)
    console.log("req.session : " + req.session.pwd)
    console.log("data : " + data)
    if (req.session.pwd == data){
        next();
    }else{
        console.log("I pass here")
        res.render('login', { title: 'Door Control' });
    }
});
```

}

in terminal :

```
    string
    string
    req.session : toto le rigolo
    data : toto le rigolo

    I pass here
    GET /api/door1 304 14.791 ms - -
```

thank you for your help

Comment: I think the `data` contains _non printable_ chars, try trim them before compare: `data.trim()`

Comment: it's good thank you very much